# JavaScript if statment don't work

Tags: javascript

I need help with javascript. here is my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var ime = document.getElementById('ime');
        var prezime = document.getElementById('prezime');
        var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon');
        var datum = document.getElementById('datum');
        var patt1 = /^\+[0-9]+$/;
        if (telefon.match(patt1) == null) {
            alert("Niste dobro uneli broj");

        }
        if (ime.value.length == 0 && prezime.value.length == 0 && telefon.value.length == 0 && datum.value.length == 0) {
            alert("Niste dobro uneli podatke!");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
<form action="popup.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">Vase ime:
    <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime"> <br/>
    Vase prezime:
    <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime"> <br/>
    Broj telefona:
    <input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon"> <br/>
    Datum rodjenja:
    <input type="text" name="datum" id="datum"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="sacuvaj">
</form>
```

I don't understand why `telefon.match(patt1)==null)` doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Should you be allowing for dashes and/or spaces in the phone number? /^\+[\d\-\s]+$/ or something like that, then just trim it?

Comment: In JavaScript you shouldn't put the opening curly braces on a new line like you do with other languages

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex%20javascript?sort=active&pagesize=50 for examples of how to better ask your question. Specifically your title should describe the question you are trying to ask; there should not be unnecessary code (such as this HTML), you should define what you'd like your code to do, and (as you did) say what part you are having trouble with. In general the question should be relevant for future users of the site.

Comment: I'll change title of my question immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is because you can't apply regex to HTML Element, you can apply it to its value:

```
var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon').value;
```

Then you can execute your regex on var telefon

Answer (score 0):

telefon is a DOM element, not a string

telefon.value can be matched

Answer (score 0):

The object stored in `telefon` will be a DOM element (e.g. `HTMLDivElement`), which has no method "match".  You'll want to extract the pertinent text from that element before matching.  How you do that will depend on the exact DOM type:

```
if (telefon.value.match(patt1) == null) // For form elements...

if (telefon.innerHTML.match(patt1) == null) // For "plain" DOM elements...
```